# How to convert a view-based iOS project an universal build?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a view-based iOS cocoa touch application built and is running on iPhone.
Now I need to convert it as an universal application in order to run that on both iPhone and iPad.
I dont know how to change a view-based as an universal build application.
How can I convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the project in Xcode. Under the Targets menu (in Groups & Files), right click on your app. Select "Upgrade current target for iPad...".