# How to change a project created for iPhone to ipad (Universal)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I was started my application for targeting iPhone, now I want to use my app for iPad also. As I started as iPhone project, even though I add the iPad xib, it is not showing properly, How to convert my project which will work for both iPhone and iPad(Universal). Any way to change in project setting?

Comment: Hi. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-iphone-app-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407116/how-to-convert-a-view-based-ios-project-an-universal-build

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-iphone-app-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the project in Xcode. Under the Targets menu ,right click on your app. Select "Upgrade current target for iPad.

Comment: See this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407116/how-to-convert-a-view-based-ios-project-an-universal-build

Comment: Also see this link it is also an important steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861330/convert-simple-iphone-app-to-universal-app

Answer (score 4):

Click on targets -> Summary ,then change the devices to universal.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another more user interactive way is

Click on your project-> Click on targets->iOS application target->Device->Universal.